# Get sender email address from attachment

Tags: c#, attachment, exchangewebservices

**Question**

How would I look at the attachment properties using EWS (Exchange 2013, C#) and retrieve the original sender's email address? Not the email address of the current sender, but the sender of the email that is attached to this email.

**What I Did**

Lots of googling has shown me only how to retrieve the sender of the current email and not the attachement. I do this by

```
//get sender of email to TR
EmailMessage mes = (EmailMessage)item;
String sender = mes.Sender.Address;
```

**Request**

Thoughts? Links? Sample code? I am looking for anything right now that I can use to help me load up the attachment and pull the sender email address. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the EWS, you have to treat it just like a local .msg/.eml file.

Comment: im using ews to connect to the exchange server and pull data.

Comment: I mean to retrieve the sender of the `email typed attachment` has nothing to do with EWS....

Comment: how does it not? if it is the method of which i am polling the exchange server, there must be a syntax that will query the attachment from the email for properties.

Comment: put it this way, that `email typed attachment` can be anything, I can just attach one of my local .msg (which has nothing to do with the exchange server that sent the email).

Comment: i think we are not talking about the same thing. I have an email(A1) in exchange with another email(A2) attached to it. I can pull the sender property by saying "String sender = mes.Sender.Address;" for A1. I need to do the same thing for A2 but am unable to use the same method because it is an attachment of A1. Does that make more sense?

Comment: that is my point: `email(A2)` can be anything, and need to be treated just like a local file as EWS no nothing about its email attributes...

Comment: when you say local file, do you mean i should download the attachment as a local file then query it? Because these emails are on the exchange server. I do not believe i am understanding you correctly. How is the email on the exchange server considered a local file? Also, how would i interact with it if not EWS? I am just trying to understand what you are saying more fully. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to fetch details on attached emails right?

Try This Code Snippet? Assuming _ewsService is a correctly bound service client.

```
var results = _ewsService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(100)); //fetch 100 random emails from inbox

foreach (var entry in results.Items)
{
    if (entry is EmailMessage)
    {
        var temp = EmailMessage.Bind(_service, entry.Id);

        if (entry.HasAttachments)
        {
            temp.Load(new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.Attachments));

            foreach (var singleItem in temp.Attachments)
            {
                if (singleItem is ItemAttachment)
                {
                    var attachedMail = singleItem as ItemAttachment;

                    attachedMail.Load();

                    Console.WriteLine(attachedMail.Item is EmailMessage);

                    var workingMessage = attachedMail.Item as EmailMessage; //this should give you from, subject, body etc etc.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code sample. I will try it out now and report back asap.

Comment: This worked for all but the smime encrypted messages. Thanks!